# What's the "?P<tag>" register rest api construct, what is for and where to find official docs?

Tags: rest-api, regex

I noticed that often in register_rest_routes, are used regexp like `?P<lang>`, `?P<category_id>\d+` and so on, but I guess it's not standard regexp syntax. What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a *[path variable](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#path-variables)*:

> Path variables enable us to add *dynamic routes*.

See below example taken from the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/):

```php
// Here we are registering our route for single products. The (?P<id>[\d]+) is
// our path variable for the ID, which, in this example, can only be some form
// of positive number.
register_rest_route( 'my-shop/v1', '/products/(?P<id>[\d]+)', array(
    ...
    'callback' => 'prefix_get_product',
) );
```

> The important part to note is that in the second route we register
>   (the one above), we add on a path variable `/(?P<id>[\d]+)` to our
>   resource path `/products`. The path variable is a regular expression.
>   In this case it uses `[\d]+` to signify that should be any numerical
>   character at least once. If you are using numeric IDs for your
>   resources, then this is a great example of how to use a path variable.
>   When using path variables, we now have to be careful around what can
>   be matched as it is user input.

And the format is: `?P<{name}>{regex pattern}`.

And based on the above example, one could go to `http://example.com/wp-json/my-shop/v1/products/123` to retrieve a single resource.

*PS: I edited mainly to add the second paragraph above.*